# Fix duplicate classes in android build.gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am developing an application on react-native.
I have a duplicate class issue raised by Gradle when I try to compile my application.

Here is the error log :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkLocalDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderMark found in modules commons-io-2.4.0.jar (org.lucee:commons-io:2.4.0) and commons-io-2.6.jar (commons-io:commons-io:2.6)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.io.Charsets found in modules commons-io-2.4.0.jar (org.lucee:commons-io:2.4.0) and commons-io-2.6.jar (commons-io:commons-io:2.6)
... (and many more)
```

I looked up online solutions, and I want to exclude one dependency, the lower version one, from the build. That way, I think the build will work.

I ran `app:dependencies` to find which packages are using this duplicate dependency :

```
--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.63.4
|   ...
+--- project :expo-constants
|    ...
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6
+--- project :expo-file-system
|    ...
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:1.4 -> 2.6
|    ...
+--- com.bridgefy:android-sdk:1.1.28
|    ...
|    +--- org.lucee:commons-io:2.4.0
|    ...
```

Now, I added this to my `app/build.gradle` file :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // I ADDED THIS LINE BELOW
    implementation('com.bridgefy:android-sdk:1.1.28') {
        exclude group: 'org.lucee', module: 'commons-io'
    }
}
```

The error doesn't go away with this... I think the module isn't excluded, yet I thought this was the way. How to fix this, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by using this configuration, `app/build.gradle` :

```
...
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'org.lucee', module: 'commons-io'
}
...
```

My error was that I was writing this line inside the `dependencies {}` block.